# Pandas: fill missing value based on combination in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, search, replace, row

I have a DataFrame `df` containing i.a. a column for `postal codes` and a column for `district` names. A `postal code` and `district` name on the same row form a 'real life' combination, e.g. `{'postal code': '10001', 'district':'North'}`.

For some of the `postal code` entries, the `district` name is missing. However, the `postal code` with missing `district` name could appear elsewhere in the dataframe, in combination with its `district` name. I.e.,

```
| postal code |   district  |
-----------------------------
|   10001     |    North    |
|   10002     |    West     |
|   10001     |   missing   |
```

In case a `postal code` has a missing `district` name, I want to search the DataFrame on combinations with that particular `postal code` and the `district` names.

If combinations are found, and are all the same, I want to replace the missing `district` name for the `district` name in the found combinations. 
If combinations are found, but are not all the same (e.g. the `postal code` overlaps two districts), I do not want to replace.

How do I go about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.replace('missing', np.nan).sort_values(['postal code', 'district'])
df.groupby('postal code').ffill().sort_index()

   postal code district
0        10001    North
1        10002     West
2        10001    North
```

I sort because `np.nan` will be placed at the end and ready to be forward filled.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm!

Comment: @LucSpan glad I could help.